# Javascript is not working properly on product view page magento , but only for a part of the products?

Tags: php, configurable-product, javascript, magento-1, jquery

i'm looking to solve a problem for few days now ! I have a website in some pages the javascript is loaded properly but in some of them not i'm getting some errors in console !
I will post an example with a good page and one with a bad one !
**Good Page**

http://www.abcsports.co.uk/index.php/mens/2015-under-armour-boys-heatgear-tech-big-logo-short-sleeve-training-t-shirt.html

**Bad page :**
http://www.abcsports.co.uk/index.php/mens/bottoms/golf-shorts/under-armour-2016-ua-heatgear-match-play-paterned-flat-front-mens-golf-shorts.html

On the good page sliders and tabs are displayed properly but in the bad ones the slider , tabs , all javascript cant be executed !

I really appreciate if somebody can help me with this !
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in a double-quote (**`"`**) at an option name (label):

[image: json parse problem in console]

Get rid of this symbol and your problem will be solved. Or you can escape you string using the `\` symbol, like: `\"`

Usually double-quotes are used for definition of the beginning and the end of a string-type value in the JSON format.

You can read more on the **stackoverflow**:

1. [jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote)
2. [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json) .

#### Update:

I can reproduce this error on my local test-shop (option label is *XS 1"*):

[image: error reproduction]

After change double-quotes to the single-quotes i get next error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[image: another error]

Then I escape a labels, and almost all works fine (no errors, but...):

[image: with escape]

And finally I have found solution - using [html-entities](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) (`&quot;` for double-quotes) not breaks anything and looks good:

[image: backend]

[image: frontend without errors]

But after resaving attributes in backend the html-entity is converted to the double-quote and error comes back :(

[image: attribute lable after resave]

[image: error comes back]

Comment: Thank you Siarhey , but what is curios on the good page for example why i don't have the same issue ? Is the same Jquery (jquery-1.7.2.min.js) , why the problem is only in few pages? Only few of them , the rest of the website content is displayed well !

Comment: @CantemirAlex That is becouse on the good page your options labels not contains a double-quotes. The JSON-string on them is parsed normally and doesn't cause errors in JS (at the subsequent execution of the program)

Comment: @CantemirAlex you can change the one double-quote in the option label to the two single-quotes: `''` (in admin pannel). Visually they are equal, but doesn't cause errors

Comment: that's very help full but please can you tell where in admin panel can i do the changes ! I would really appreciate it ! Thank you again

Comment: @CantemirAlex Go to the *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes*, search the **Size** attribute: https://gyazo.com/b393d7a708e65f28801e7f1b905cf552 , click on it (edit), open the labels tab https://gyazo.com/5ca72c875ad3fb7bd7c25b32b239c2a5 and change the label **Waist 30"** (remove double-quote, add two single-quotes), save, refresh cache.

Comment: Hi Siarhey , thank you for your answer ! I have tried to do that but still not working ! :(

Comment: @CantemirAlex You should avoid using the double-quotes in the labels. Try to replace all of them with the `&quot;`. After the saving & cleaning the cache all should work. In my opinion - this is possible magento bug.

Comment: Thank you Siarhey , i will do that ! Thanks again for your help i really appreciate it !